# Export PNG image in Sketch, looks poor quality

Tags: icon, sketch-app, interface-design, artboard, anti-aliasing

I'm using Sketch 51 on a macOS High Sierra. The Instagram icon looks great in Sketch but when I export as PNG it loses a lot of quality.

[image]

To the right we can see the icon in Sketch with zoom in good quality, and to the left we can see the image once exported.

I export the image with these options:
- First I create an Artboard and adjust it to the image
- Icon size is 45x45
- I export the artboard and choose PNG

[image]

Comment: have you checked it in Sketch with "Show Pixels on Zoom" activated?

Comment: @Luciano Thanks, I have to save it with 3x to make it look good.

Comment: Hi Antonio. Welcome to GDSE. The image apprears to be zoomed in. Try viewing it at 100%. Don't zoom in on raster images or you will see pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Scale down, not up. Scaling up will lose quality. Find the original image at the largest file size you will use, then export the others to the smaller dimensions.